# How to create a multi-dictionary call for a large dataframe

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have created a simple dataframe for explanation purposes, however the original dataframe is much bigger with more than 100 columns and thousands rows.
`

```
data = {'Name': ['James', 'Miriam', 'Josh', 'Peter'],
        'ID': [11,12,13,14],
        'Tester': [0,0,1,1],
       'Developer':[1,0,0,1],
       'Architect':[0,1,0,1],
       'Engineer':[1,1,0,0],
       'Cyber_security':[1,0,0,0],
       'IT_support':[0,1,0,0],
       'Business_analyst':[0,0,0,1]}
```

```
    Name    ID  Tester  Developer   Architect   Engineer    Cyber_security  IT_support  Business_analyst
0   James   11  0   1   0   1   1   0   0
1   Miriam  12  0   0   1   1   0   1   0
2   Josh    13  1   0   0   0   0   0   0
3   Peter   14  1   1   1   0   0   0   1
```

`

I am trying to find a single code that will automatically create separate dictionaries for every single column having always as a reference the 'Name' column. Also I would like to name those dictionaries with the same name of the column but adding "dict" or "list" to the name.

What I got at the moment is the following:

```
`
lstName = list ( df.Name )
dictTester = dict ( zip ( list( df.Name ), list ( df.Tester )))
dictDeveloper = dict ( zip ( list ( df.Name ), list ( df.Developer )))
dictArchitect = dict ( zip ( list ( df.Name ), list ( df.Architect )))
dictEngineer = dict ( zip ( list ( df.Name ), list ( df.Engineer )))
dictCyber_security = dict ( zip ( list ( df.Name ), list ( df.Cyber_security )))
dictIT_support= dict ( zip ( list ( df.Name ), list ( df.IT_support )))
dictBusiness_analyst = dict ( zip ( list ( df.Name ), list ( df.Business_analyst )))`
```

This works well, however if I want to do this with more than 100 columns, the codes will be a bit too long.

Can please anyone advice me how to get all in a single code and at the same time be able to name each dictionary as the codes above (dict+columnname) so I will be able to call each dictionary independently later on to add them in constraints in a model.

Comment: This seems like an [x y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Why make so many variables when you already have it in dict form?

Comment: I just created the dictionary to be able to post an example here but the real data is a transformed csv format with couple of concatenations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this would work?

```
In [41]: dff = df.to_dict(orient="list")

In [42]: for key, val in dff.items():
    ...:     if key == "Name":
    ...:         continue
    ...:     d ={key: {name:value for name, value in zip(dff["Name"], val)}}
    ...:     print(d)
    ...:
{'ID': {'James': 11, 'Miriam': 12, 'Josh': 13, 'Peter': 14}}
{'Tester': {'James': 0, 'Miriam': 0, 'Josh': 1, 'Peter': 1}}
{'Developer': {'James': 1, 'Miriam': 0, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 1}}
{'Architect': {'James': 0, 'Miriam': 1, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 1}}
{'Engineer': {'James': 1, 'Miriam': 1, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 0}}
{'Cyber_security': {'James': 1, 'Miriam': 0, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 0}}
{'IT_support': {'James': 0, 'Miriam': 1, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 0}}
{'Business_analyst': {'James': 0, 'Miriam': 0, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 1}}
```

Not sure if that is what you want?

Updated answer that defines variables:

```
In [139]:
     ...: for key, val in dff.items():
     ...:     if key == "Id":
     ...:         continue
     ...:     variable_name = f"dict{key}"
     ...:     value = {name:value for name, value in zip(dff["Name"], val)}
     ...:     # This was wrong.
     ...:     # exec("variable_name = value")
     ...:     # Fix
     ...:     exec(f"{variable_name} = value")

In [140]: dictDeveloper
Out[140]: {'James': 1, 'Miriam': 0, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 1}
```

Comment: Thank you Aidis. It is quite similar, however what I am looking for is something like if I call Tester (ideally I change the name to dictID so I avoid confusion in future codes), I get a separated output like this:  {'James': 0,
 'Miriam': 0,
 'Josh': 1,
 'Peter': 1}
 Then, if I need to call Developer (or better dictDeveloper), I would need a separted output like this:  {'James': 1,
 'Miriam': 0,
 'Josh': 0,
 'Peter': 1}, and so on with every single combination.

Comment: So you want to have results in variables like `dictTester`?
You can store things I printed into a dictionary and access them like `data["tester"]`. Would that be good enough? or please explain me what you want exactly.

Comment: I added another answer, check it out.

Comment: Hi, Yes, that looks like the perfect code and result. However, it seems that the variable name is not recognized as, when I call dictDeveloper I get a NameError: name 'dictDeveloper' is not defined .

Comment: I do not see how you run the code, hard to comment why you get the error. Maybe the names of the original dict were changed? Or maybe you try to access the variable before running the variable definition loop?

Comment: Maybe it has to be with the exec() function. Basically if I run the full code and then I call variable_name and then value I get the same results for both variables: {'James': 0, 'Miriam': 0, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 1}. However, if I run the loop without the exec() function and then I call variable_name I get: 'dictBusiness_analyst', if then I call value I get {'James': 0, 'Miriam': 0, 'Josh': 0, 'Peter': 1}. But still in both cases if I call dictDeveloper or any other I get same error.

Comment: There was a mistake done by me. I updated the answer.

Comment: Oh I see, That is brilliant! Everything is working well now. This is exactly the output I was looking for. I really appreciate your help. Thank you very much